# How to generate multiple sums within a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, etl

Below you can see my query, which gives the following result:

```
select t.actual_date, 
   t.id_key, 
   t.attendance_status, 
   t.money_step, 
   sum(t.money_step) over (partition by t.id_key order by t.actual_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)as accumulated
from example t
order by t.id_key, t.actual_date
```

[image]

Results of the query

I want the "accumulated" column to add up the value of "money_step" for each id_key. If the id_key  is the second time '15' for an Id, the counter should add up from the beginning. For ID_KEY = 1 it should look like this:

accumulated:

```
Row 1:20
Row 2: 80
Row 3: 100
Row 4: 120
```

For ID_KEY = 2 ist should look like:

```
Row 1: accumulated = 30; attendance_status = 7
Row 2: accumulated = 130; attendance_status = 15
Row 3: accumulated = 30; attendance_status = 15
Row 4: accumulated = 60; attendance_status = 15
```

Level 15 always has the latest date. From the second date of level 15, the sum should restart for each id. All values ​​less than 15 should be counted as normal.

How can I do this in the query? Can someone help me?

Comment: Not understanding the part, second time 15 for an id. you mean, if it is 15, it should be from the beginning ?

Comment: What about `id_key` `2`?

Comment: @VenkataramanR yes exactly! It should start from the beginning. Sorry for my english.

Comment: @Larnu it should work like the same principle:
attendance_status 1-15: count normal 
attendance_status = 15 (second 15 for the id with a bigger actual date): count from zero

Comment: There are attendances with `7` and `8`, so where do those come into it? Include a full expected result set, we shouldn't need to guess.

Comment: @Larnu I hope it is more understandable now. 15 always has the most current date.

Comment: second consecutive 15? or there can be 15, 10, 15?

Comment: @mkRabbani second consecutive 15 :-)! The sum should just start again to count for the second 15 with the same id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below logic-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7890c1852fd31be5cfe107599935cdb5)

```
SELECT *,
SUM(A.money_step) over (
    partition by A.id_key, A.P 
    ORDER BY A.actual_date 
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
)as accumulated
FROM
(
    SELECT A.*,
    (
        SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) >= 2 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
        FROM your_table B 
        WHERE B.id_key = A.id_key
        AND B.actual_date <= A.actual_date
        AND attendance_status = 15
    ) P
    FROM your_table A
)A
ORDER BY A.id_key,A.actual_date
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, as I'm not transcribing an image, however, I *think* this will work. If not, then consumable sample data is must here:

```
WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT t.actual_date,
            t.id_key,
            t.attendance_status,
            t.money_step,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.id_key,
                                            CASE attendance_status WHEN 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                               ORDER BY t.actual_date) AS RN
     FROM example t)
SELECT C.actual_date,
       C.id_key,
       C.attendance_status,
       C.money_step,
       SUM(t.money_step) OVER (PARTITION BY t.id_key, CASE WHEN RN > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                               ORDER BY t.actual_date
                               ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS accumulated
FROM CTE C;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise you to do this only using window functions.  It is actually pretty simple:

```
SELECT t.*,
       SUM(t.money_step) OVER (PARTITION BY id_key, grp ORDER BY actual_date) as accumulated
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             SUM(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 AND attendance_status = 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER
                 (PARTITION BY id_key ORDER BY actual_date) as grp
      FROM (SELECT t.*,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_key, attendance_status ORDER BY actual_date) as seqnum
            FROM t
           ) t
     ) t
ORDER BY t.id_key, t.actual_date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a38bb30e3c0e6e48ae94dffb94c1fda1) is a db<>fiddle.